# Sed replace characters in a string

Tags: linux, replace, sed, find, vi

I've got a file with a string (the 1,2,3 will vary):

```
{"var": [1,2,3]}
```

I want to replace it to look like so:

```
{"var": [4,5,6]}
```

I try this:

```
sed 's/\{"var": \[.*\]\}/\{"var": \[4,5,6\]\}/g' file.txt
```

But I get an error:

```
 Invalid preceding regular expression
```

How can I replace the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed uses some unusual escaping style: you (usually) escape symbols to make them "active", otherwise they are just characters.

So, this one works properly (without escaping the braces, plus, you're missing a dot)

```
sed 's/{"var": \[.*\]\}/\{"var": \[4,5,6\]}/g' file.txt
```

**however**, I'd recommend you not to do so, ie. use a proper json parser to open the file, change it, and save it back again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sed -r 's@(\{"var": \[)[^\]+\]@\14,5,6]}@' file.txt
```

**output**

```
{"var": [4,5,6]}}
```

- `{ }` & `[ ]` need backslashing, because it some keywords in `sed` regex
- the `-r` means *extented regex*, this need less backslashing.

Comment: Editting a file, echoing the string doesn't help

Comment: This just removes {"var": [1,2,3]} string

Comment: Possibly..  I've tried examples from the internet before and they'll give me different output than the poster

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
echo '{"var": [1,2,3]}' | sed 's/{"var": \[.*\]}/\{"var": \[4,5,6\]\}/g
```

You need `.*` to match zero or more occurences of any character. Also, I unescaped the curly braces; I'm not sure they needed to be escaped.